# How do you change the server header returned by nginx?

Tags: nginx, http-headers

There's an option to hide the version so it will display only nginx, but is there a way to hide that too so it will not show anything or change the header?

Comment: btw, to hide nginx version you need to set 'server_tokens off'.

Comment: If you care about removing nginx from the header, you might also like to remove it from redirects and error pages.

Comment: According to the [nginx docs for server_tokens](https://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#server_tokens) you can only customize or remove the `Server` header in nginx if you have the commercial subscription. However you can also use the `proxy_pass_header Server;` trick and have your back-end remove the header as well (in that case nginx doesn't add any Server header).

Answer (score 63, accepted):

Like Apache, this is a quick edit to the source and recompile. From [Calomel.org](https://calomel.org/nginx.html):

> The Server: string is the header which
>   is sent back to the client to tell
>   them what type of http server you are
>   running and possibly what version.
>   This string is used by places like
>   Alexia and Netcraft to collect
>   statistics about how many and of what
>   type of web server are live on the
>   Internet. To support the author and
>   statistics for Nginx we recommend
>   keeping this string as is. But, for
>   security you may not want people to
>   know what you are running and you can
>   change this in the source code. Edit
>   the source file
>   `src/http/ngx_http_header_filter_module.c`
>   at look at lines 48 and 49. You can
>   change the String to anything you
>   want.

```
## vi src/http/ngx_http_header_filter_module.c (lines 48 and 49)
static char ngx_http_server_string[] = "Server: MyDomain.com" CRLF;
static char ngx_http_server_full_string[] = "Server: MyDomain.com" CRLF;
```

**March 2011 edit:** Props to Flavius below for pointing out a new option, replacing Nginx's standard [HttpHeadersModule](http://wiki.nginx.org/HttpHeadersModule) with the forked [HttpHeadersMoreModule](http://wiki.nginx.org/HttpHeadersMoreModule). Recompiling the standard module is still the quick fix, and makes sense if you want to use the standard module and won't be changing the server string often. But if you want more than that, the HttpHeadersMoreModule is a strong project and lets you do all sorts of runtime black magic with your HTTP headers.

Comment: using 'server_tokens off;' is by far the easiest way to do it ... make sure to put it in a "http" or "server" block

Comment: That hides the version number, but the question was "I know I can hide the version number, how do I change or delete the entire 'Server' string?" There's no way to do that using out-of-the-box nginx.

Comment: Another quick fix (for version 1.7.8) to completely remove the server header is: comment out lines 49 and 50 (corresponding to lines 48, 49 above), 280-283 and 458-469. For future reference: the last two are both if-blocks that set `r->headers_out.server`.

Comment: This answer is a little but old now. The answer of @jamescampbell is more acurate now.

Comment: If you plan to use this method to mask your server, you may also want to edit the src/http/ngx_http_special_response.c file to change the server's error messages.

Comment: How can i do it using add_header?

Comment: Hi, does anyone know what to do if the host do not allow us to add additional modules for nginx? In that case, what other possible solutions do we have?

Answer (score 169):

If you are using nginx to proxy a back-end application and want the back-end to advertise its own `Server:` header without nginx overwriting it, then you can go inside of your `server {…}` stanza and set:

```
proxy_pass_header Server;
```

That will convince nginx to leave that header alone and not rewrite the value set by the back-end.

Comment: If you're making this change because of security reasons, I'm not sure this is enough.  If your server needs to return an error message, the header will still be 'nginx'

Comment: though this solves the issue easily, however there is one thing to take into account: when using a reverse proxy the static files are being served through nginx, so when you open e.g. image in firebug net panel you can still see the server as nginx

Comment: IMO, this is the best answer.  This solution doesn't require any special software extension, and works with the base nginx.

Comment: this worked for me for Tornado, and since in tornado you can return a custom header, this is the best answer, added to tornado `self.set_header("Server", "Custom name")`

Comment: This works great and even REMOVES the header entirely if your back-end does not return the header. In ASP.NET core with Kestrel, you can omit the header via `builder.WebHost.ConfigureKestrel((ArgWebHostBuilderContext, ArgKestrelServerOptions) => {
  ArgKestrelServerOptions.AddServerHeader = false;
});` and in this case nginx won't return a `Server` header at all.

Answer (score 118):

The last update was a while ago, so here is what worked for me on Ubuntu:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install nginx-extras
```

And then:

1. `sudo nano /etc/nginx/nginx.conf`
2. set this as first line of /etc/nginx/nginx.conf or else nginx will DIE on restart

   ```
   load_module modules/ngx_http_headers_more_filter_module.so;
   ```
3. Then add the following two lines to the `http` section of `nginx.conf`

   ```
   server_tokens off; # removed pound sign
   more_set_headers 'Server: Eff_You_Script_Kiddies!';
   ```

Also, don't forget to restart nginx with `sudo service nginx restart`.

Comment: Is there something similar on YUM? yum install nginx-extras did not work.

Comment: @PKHunter I haven't tried it in the devil's tongue of YUM but I will see what I can find.

Comment: @PKHunter apparently sudo yum install epel-release and then sudo yum install nginx will ensure you install the latest release of nginx which shouldn't require nginx-extras. Try setting the flag I mentioned in the conf file and restart nginx and let me know if that works.

Comment: Setting an empty string to Server: will suppress the server header:`more_set_headers 'Server: ';`

Comment: @jamescampbell, thank you for `sudo yum install epel-release`. Did that. But I cannot 'install' Nginx. I need to update my 1.8.1 copy. So I did `sudo yum update nginx`. Which has brought the version up to 1.10.3. Even with this, I get the error: `unknown directive "more_set_headers"`

Comment: @CodyCraven yes that removes server from response header

Comment: BTW, install by directly download referring from [openresty/headers-more-nginx-module](https://github.com/openresty/headers-more-nginx-module#installation) (Now [header_more](https://www.nginx.com/resources/wiki/modules/headers_more/) is moved to GitHub).

Comment: Thank you this works like a charm without any recompiling of any sort. Well done ;)

Comment: Answer is good for debian systems. Couldn't find a 'package manager' solution for Redhat based system. In my case CentOS. Nginx's repo provides 'server_tokens off' as a built in option. But, the option for more_set_headers is not valid directive. Couldn't find a separate module listed in YUM. However, there is a package called 'nginx-all-modules.noarch' . I haven't tried it. So, I am not sure it this contains the necessary module.

Comment: I tried 'nginx-all-modules.noarch' too. That too doesn't contain 'more_set_headers'. The way out is perhaps a rule in CDN/Varnish if you have it before Web Server. Or Nginx installation using source code.

Comment: Yes. I did go through the instructions on GitHub page. Like I said, it needs to be compiled from source. There are no packaged (RPM) version. So, I left it at that. At the moment, I have worked around it through Akamai. 
Let's say if I compile it using source code on another server, then what files other than 'ngx_http_headers_more_filter_module.so' would I need to copy over to a RPM installed Nginx?

Comment: **`sudo apt-get install nginx-extras`**

then inside **nginx.conf**
go to http section and add these two lines
`server_tokens off;
more_clear_headers Server;`

Comment: No solution for RedHat folks -- RH, CentOS, Fedora. Still stuck with the recompile stuff. Sad..

Comment: @PKHunter I think I may have found something. If you install a different version of nginx that has extra things already added. `sudo yum -y install https://extras.getpagespeed.com/release-latest.rpm
sudo yum -y install yum-utils
sudo yum-config-manager --enable getpagespeed-extras-nginx-mod
sudo yum -y install nginx
sudo systemctl enable --now nginx` then: "With NGINX-MOD, you can specify a new value none, which will cause NGINX to stop emission of its presence on the server:

server_tokens none;" from https://www.getpagespeed.com/nginx-mod-a-better-faster-nginx-build

Comment: Thanks. But the getpagespeed repo is now paid at a ridiculously high price: $50 per *month*.

Comment: @PKHunter FML. that is ridiculous. Want to compile a custom version of nginx together and brand it and charge $50 per day? lol

Comment: any solution for yum ?

Comment: @YogeshJilhawar just my comment above that would work but you need to pay for the getpagespeed-extras-nginx-mod. I am sure you can try to compile nginx-extras from scratch otherwise...

Comment: @YogeshJilhawar also the other answer below "The only way is to modify the file src/http/ngx_http_header_filter_module.c . I changed nginx on line 48 to a different string"

Comment: Also, don't forget to add `load_module modules/ngx_http_headers_more_filter_module.so;` to your config

Answer (score 43):

It’s very simple: Add these lines to server section:

```
server_tokens off;
more_set_headers 'Server: My Very Own Server';
```

Comment: You have to compile nginx with 3th party module  http://wiki.nginx.org/HttpHeadersMoreModule for that

Comment: On Ubuntu you can install `nginx-extra` to get that module.

Comment: if we are to believe apt-get autoexpansion, it is nginx-extras   with an "s" at the end

Comment: Note, you need the "Server: " prefix to override the existing Server: value .

Answer (score 34):

Simple, edit /etc/nginx/nginx.conf and remove comment from

```
#server_tokens off;
```

Search for *http* section.

Comment: this works nice, once you do this all you can see about the server on the headers info is :nginx (no version number)   Thanks! :D

Comment: The author of the question is already aware of this option, which removes the version number, but doesn't allow you to customize the value that is returned in the "server" header.

Comment: This doesn't hide everything, but only the server version.

Comment: Does not remove the response header for Server=nginx

Comment: I think passing the version of nginx is a security concern. So for many people, this is a "good enough" solution. Also it is worth noting that this will have to go into each server block, in case you have a server block for port 80 and 443.

Answer (score 30):

Install Nginx Extras

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install nginx-extras
```

Server details can be removed from response by adding following two lines in the nginx.conf (under http section)

```
more_clear_headers Server;
server_tokens off;
```

Comment: One, this is what @jamescampbell above mentioned. Second, this requires Nginx to be compiled from source (`yum install nginx-extras` doesn't work -- I suppose this works on Debia/Ubuntu etc with the `apt-get`.)

Comment: It works without having nginx compiled from source. You only need to load the module: ngx_http_headers_more_filter_module from nginx.conf

Comment: after running "apt-get install nginx-extras", it downgraded the version of my nginx from 1.16 to 1.14

Comment: works great on raspberry where it seems that the latest supported nginx version is 1.14.2 as of today. No need to recompile here.

Comment: What is nginx-extras?

Answer (score 27):

There is a special module: http://wiki.nginx.org/NginxHttpHeadersMoreModule

> This module allows you to add, set, or clear any output or input header that you specify.
>
> This is an enhanced version of the standard [headers](https://web.archive.org/web/20100209015711/http://wiki.nginx.org/NginxHttpHeadersModule) module because it provides more utilities like resetting or clearing "builtin headers" like `Content-Type`, `Content-Length`, and `Server`.
>
> It also allows you to specify an optional HTTP status code criteria using the `-s` option and an optional content type criteria using the `-t` option while modifying the output headers with the [more_set_headers](https://web.archive.org/web/20100209015711/http://wiki.nginx.org/NginxHttpHeadersMoreModule#more_set_headers) and [more_clear_headers](https://web.archive.org/web/20100209015711/http://wiki.nginx.org/NginxHttpHeadersMoreModule#more_clear_headers) directives...

Comment: Compile nginx with `--add-module=/path-to-headers-more-nginx-module`

Comment: Looks like this was moved to OpenResty: https://github.com/openresty/headers-more-nginx-module#readme

Comment: Is there any way to get this module without having to recompile nginx from source for Centos 7?

Answer (score 19):

If you're okay with just changing the header to another string five letters or fewer, you can simply patch the binary.

```
sed -i 's/nginx\r/thing\r/' `which nginx`
```

Which, as a solution, has a few notable advantages. Namely, that you can allow your nginx versioning to be handled by the package manager (so, no compiling from source) even if nginx-extras isn't available for your distro, and you don't need to worry about any of the additional code of something like nginx-extras being vulnerable.

Of course, you'll also want to set the option `server_tokens off`, to hide the version number, or patch that format string as well.

I say "five letters or fewer" because of course you can always replace:

> nginx\r\0

with

> bob\r\0\r\0

leaving the last two bytes unchanged.

If you actually want more than five characters, you'll want to leave server_tokens on, and replace the (slightly longer) format string, although again there's an upper limit on that length imposed by the length of the format string - 1 (for the carriage return).

...If none of the above makes sense to you, or you've never patched a binary before, you may want to stay away from this approach, though.

Comment: Only for people compiling nginx from scratch though.

Comment: @PKHunter hm? The advantage of this is that it works *without* having to compile from scratch. No source code involved. It's patching the compiled *binary* directly.

Comment: Ooh, this sounds promising. So if I wanted to change the server name from "nginx" to "abcde" (5 characters as you indicated) what precisely am I doing? Am I executing a command in `/usr/sbin` to replace a string inside a binary?

Comment: Usually `sed` is in `/bin`, but yeah. Specifically, you're relying on the fact that the string `nginx\r` (where `\r` means the carriage return character) only appears once in the binary. But the point is the *only* times that sequence of characters occurs is as a part of the constant Server header string.

Comment: It's not aware of file format at all- it's just replacing a sequence of bytes with a different sequence of bytes- so it's always worthwhile to actually verify that the sequence of bytes you're replacing really is just the string you want to replace and not, say, executable code in a subroutine (which is pretty unlikely, but still).

Comment: So you'd just run that `sed` command above, the `\`which nginx\`` part returns the path to the binary, and the `sed` command does the byte replacement.

Comment: The null bytes mentioned later in the answer refer to the fact that you can use shorter headers than the full length of the string so long as you end the replacement with a null byte. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Null-terminated_string

Comment: @ParthianShot, this is a very interesting solution. As far as I'm concerned this should be the right answer :) THANK you.

Comment: @ParthianShot How in in which context should the command be used? I get the following error: "sed: no input files"

Comment: I get this message--  `sed: can't read is: No such file or directory`

Comment: For those who are having problems... Either you don't have nginx installed at all ( :P ), or the binary for nginx isn't in one of the directories in the `PATH` environment variable passed to the subshell (which means either you need to make sure `PATH` is exported, or you simply need to change your `PATH`). Or I suppose you might be using a shell not based on the Bourne shell...

Comment: @ParthianShot `which nginx` shows /usr/sbin/nginx. Isn't that the executable? It is in the path, which is why it shows this file?

Comment: @ParthianShot, also `whereis nginx` shows 
`nginx: /usr/sbin/nginx.old /usr/sbin/nginx /usr/lib64/nginx /etc/nginx /usr/share/nginx`  -- which of these could I edit with SED command? I tried with /usr/sbin/nginx, but it doesn't do anything. The others tell me `couldn't edit /usr/share/nginx: not a regular file`...

Comment: Ah. Yes, it is the executable. And you would also need to be a user with write permission to the file. And I wouldn't be surprised if you needed to restart `nginx` for the changes to take effect. All that said? I urge you not to use one of the other answers. If all the things I'm saying aren't already familiar to you, and you don't know what the `/etc` directory is for, then a hack like this is kind of dangerous.

Comment: `/etc/nginx` would be the `nginx` config directory. Since it's a directory, the `write` syscall and other normal file I/O operations won't work (unless you're on a very old version of UNIX).

Comment: I found that Nginx was in `/sbin/nginx`. So I executed the command on that file, and restarted Nginx. It seems to work for http. But for httpS, somehow the usual "nginx" server header is sent back. So this method doesn't work for us anyway.

Comment: Interesting... So I'd grep for the `nginx` string in the binary to see how many times it appears, then I'd use `xxd` or something to get the hex of the file and search for `nginx` in that to find the header for HTTPS. (I'd use `grep` first to see the number of matches, so that in the hexdump if the string is at a line boundary and gets broken the discrepancy in `grep` match count is noticeable.)

Answer (score 6):

According to nginx [documentation](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#server_tokens) it supports custom values or even the exclusion:

```
Syntax: server_tokens on | off | build | string;
```

but sadly only with a *commercial subscription*:

> Additionally, as part of our commercial subscription, starting from
>   version 1.9.13 the signature on error pages and the “Server” response
>   header field value can be set explicitly using the string with
>   variables. An empty string disables the emission of the “Server”
>   field.

Comment: That's for nginx PLUS, which is a paid enterprise version of the server.

Answer (score 3):

After I read Parthian Shot's answer, I dig into `/usr/sbin/nginx` binary file. Then I found out that the file contains these three lines.

```
Server: nginx/1.12.2
Server: nginx/1.12.2
Server: nginx
```

Basically first two of them are meant for `server_tokens on;` directive (Server version included).
Then I change the search criteria to match those lines within the binary file.

```
sed -i 's/Server: nginx/Server: thing/' `which nginx`
```

After I dig farther I found out that the error message produced by nginx is also included in this file.

```
<hr><center>nginx</center>
```

There are three of them, one without the version, two of them included the version. So I run the following command to replace nginx string within the error message.

```
sed -i 's/center>nginx/center>thing/' `which nginx`
```

Comment: Thanks for this. But your first command executed inside `/usr/sbin` folder yields this: `sed: can't read is: No such file or directory`

Comment: >"There are three of them, one without the version, two of them included the version." I patched them all, but from a quick test I saw that `server_tokens off;` also produces the HTML *without* the version (in addition to producing the `Server` header without the version string).

Answer (score 3):

Expanding on Parthian Shot's answer, you can actually replace the whole header and not only the value as long as the total length is the same:

```
sed -i 's/Server: nginx/My-Header: hi/' `which nginx`
```

Answer (score 2):

The only way is to modify the file src/http/ngx_http_header_filter_module.c . I changed nginx on line 48 to a different string.

What you can do in the nginx config file is to set *server_tokens* to off. This will prevent nginx from printing the version number.

To check things out, try *curl -I http://vurbu.com/ | grep Server*

It should return

```
Server: Hai
```

Comment: Well, that's not the only way. Other alternatives have been shown in other responses.

Comment: Most people do not install from source. They use a repo installer like yum or dnf.

Answer (score 2):

I know the post is kinda old, but I have found a solution easy that works on Debian based distribution without compiling nginx from source.

First install nginx-extras package

> sudo apt install nginx-extras

Then load the nginx http headers more module by editing nginx.conf and adding the following line inside the server block

> load_module modules/ngx_http_headers_more_filter_module.so;

Once it's done you'll have access to both more_set_headers and more_clear_headers directives.

Answer (score 0):

Newest openresty version , just add `more_clear_headers "Server";` in the location block:

```
location / {
        root   html;
        #index  index.html index.htm;
        default_type 'text/plain';
        content_by_lua 'ngx.say("Hello World!")';
        more_clear_headers "Server";
    }
```

Answer (score -1):

Nginx-extra package is deprecated now.

The following therefore did now work for me as i tried installing various packages
more_set_headers 'Server: My Very Own Server';

You can just do the following and no server or version information will be sent back

```
    server_tokens '';
```

if you just want to remove the version number this works

```
   server_tokens off;
```

Comment: Your solution produces the following error `nginx: [emerg] invalid value "suckit" in /etc/nginx...`

Comment: @AltimusPrime, just set empty quotes. Don't pass any string in between the quotes. It works like a charm. Thanks LazyDeveloper

Comment: @LazyDeveloper An empty string value also doesn't work

Comment: did not work for me too

Comment: please note: i am using Nginx Plus - paid version. I am not sure if this is restricted in the free version.

Answer (score -3):

Are you asking about the Server header value in the response? You can try changing that with an add_header directive, but I'm not sure if it'll work. http://wiki.codemongers.com/NginxHttpHeadersModule

Comment: yes, the server header. but isn't there a cleaner way like on lighttpd for example where i just have server.tag="whatever"? the add_header works only for response codes 200, 204, 301, 302 or 304, so if server will somehow do a 500 it will not work