# How to change Server Name in HTTP Response Header?

Tags: http, header, nginx, response

Is it possible to change your server name in HTTP Response Headers from nginx to something else. I want to do it to confuse prying eyes and enhanced security.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do you change server tag for nginx?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/246227/how-do-you-change-server-tag-for-nginx)

Answer (score 1):

You will need to go into the core code, find where this is, change this and recompile Nginx.

Not worth the trouble really.

There is the server tokens directive that will hide the version number. http://wiki.nginx.org/HttpCoreModule#server_tokens.

Not much use in terms of security either really but at least not so much trouble to achieve.