# How to change the type of web server shown

Tags: nginx

the title is not very accurate so i will try to explain here

in this page

http://browserspy.dk/webserver.php

you can put any domain and it will show you the web server they use

i would like to know how can i modify my server to show something else there
**i use centos6.4 with nginx 1.7.2**
so if someone uses the site above to check my domain instead of "nginx" to show "stack" or anything else

thank you in advance

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do you change the server header returned by nginx?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/246227/how-do-you-change-the-server-header-returned-by-nginx)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Install the `HttpHeadersMoreModule` module. - http://wiki.nginx.org/HttpHeadersMoreModule
2. Set the header `more_set_headers 'Server: my-server';`
3. Restart Nginx.

Comment: since i am a bit noob could you please advice on how to set the header?

Comment: Have you compiled with the module?

Comment: Simply add this `more_set_headers 'Server: my-server';` to the Nginx configuration. Replace `my-server` with the name you want to display.

Comment: If it works for you, please mark this as the answer. :)