# How to remove header from EB response

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, docker, flask, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I'm trying to remove a response header from an EB service.

EB configuration:
`64bit Amazon Linux 2017.03 v2.7.1 running Docker 17.03.1-ce`

Which runs:`FROM python:3.6.1`

Also using `flask`

Iv'e added the following code to `flask`:

```
def after_request_callback(response):
    response.headers["server"] = "SomeNonFingerprintValue"
    return response


def create_application():
    application = Flask(__name__)
    application.after_request(after_request_callback)
```

This works fine when I run locally, but when I deploy to EB I keep getting the fingerprint value: `server → nginx/1.10.3`

Any idea how to remove\modify this value for the deployed service?

Comment: Probably nginx is overwriting the server header. If you can modify nginx config [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33513698/21945) might help.

Comment: Yeah saw it, not sure if it's possible and how to for EB... part of the question

Answer (score 1):

1. Create an '.ebextensions' folder in the root of the project
2. Add a file called 'nginx.config' (can be called anything, as long as it ends with .config)
3. Put the following content in the file (notice the **proxy_set_header** lines):

   ```
   files:
   "/tmp/000_my_nginx_config.conf":
   mode: "000644"
   owner: root
   group: root
   content: |
     upstream nodejs {
         server 127.0.0.1:8081;
         keepalive 256;
     }

     log_format combined_no_query '$remote_addr - $remote_user [$time_local] '
       '"$uri" $status $body_bytes_sent '
       '"$http_referer" "$http_user_agent"';

     server {
       listen 8080;

       if ($time_iso8601 ~ "^(\d{4})-(\d{2})-(\d{2})T(\d{2})") {
           set $year $1;
           set $month $2;
           set $day $3;
           set $hour $4;
       }

       access_log /var/log/nginx/healthd/application.log.$year-$month-$day-$hour healthd;
       access_log  /var/log/nginx/access.log  combined_no_query;

       location / {
           proxy_pass  http://nodejs;
           proxy_set_header   Connection "";
           proxy_http_version 1.1;
           proxy_set_header        Host            $host;
           proxy_set_header        X-Real-IP       $remote_addr;
           proxy_set_header        X-Forwarded-For 
           proxy_set_header        Server NonFingerprint;
       }

       gzip on;
       gzip_comp_level 4;
       gzip_types text/html text/plain text/css application/json application/x-javascript text/xml application/xml application/xml+rss text/javascript;

     }

     "/tmp/45_replace_config.sh":
   mode: "000644"
   owner: root
   group: root
   content: |
     #! /bin/bash
     cp -rfv /tmp/000_my_nginx_config.conf /etc/nginx/conf.d/00_elastic_beanstalk_proxy.conf

   container_commands:
      00_appdeploy_rewrite_hook:
   command: cp -v /tmp/45_replace_config.sh /opt/elasticbeanstalk/hooks/appdeploy/enact
     01_appdeploy_rewrite_hook:
   command: cp -v /tmp/45_replace_config.sh /opt/elasticbeanstalk/hooks/configdeploy/enact
     02_rewrite_hook_perms:
   command: chmod 755 /opt/elasticbeanstalk/hooks/appdeploy/enact/45_replace_config.sh /opt/elasticbeanstalk/hooks/configdeploy/enact/45_replace_config.sh
     03_rewrite_hook_ownership:
   command: chown root:users /opt/elasticbeanstalk/hooks/appdeploy/enact/45_replace_config.sh /opt/elasticbeanstalk/hooks/configdeploy/enact/45_replace_config.sh
   ```