# Amazon S3 Web Server?

Tags: amazon-web-services, webserver

I am a Computer Science student and I am developing a Flask app and trying to deploy it on the web with Google Compute Engine.

From what I understood, between the end-user (client) and my Flask app, there is at least 2 major elements:

1. Web-server `(NGINX, Apache)`
2. App-Server  `(Gunicorn, Uwsgi)`
3. Your Python App (`Flask`)

I went on multiple websites to look what web-servers they were using and I saw a lot of `Amazon S3` web-server. Does it means that Amazon has it own Web-Server or they are using NGINX under the wood? I am extremely confused about it.

[image]

Comment: As a side note, it's possible to change what nginx returns as the `Server:` header from `nginx` to `your_custom_name` by compiling nginx yourself, or using the HeadersMore module: [see this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/246227/how-do-you-change-the-server-header-returned-by-nginx) for info on that.  That's not to say S3 uses nginx, but anyone could apply their custom branding to nginx in this manner.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Amazon S3 is an object storage, quoting from the [Hosting a static website on Amazon S3](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/WebsiteHosting.html) page:

> You can use Amazon S3 to host a static website. On a static website, individual webpages include static content. They might also contain client-side scripts.
> By contrast, a dynamic website relies on server-side processing, including server-side scripts such as PHP, JSP, or ASP.NET. Amazon S3 does not support server-side scripting, but AWS has other resources for hosting dynamic websites.

On the other hand, AWS offers a wide range of services to host websites which you can see [here](https://aws.amazon.com/websites/).

Comment: Thanks for your answer it's clear. So I have a Flask App, I can  host static files (public_html) on Amazon S3 and the leftover on a Uwsgi for example?

Comment: Yes, depending on the requirements you have your options from the Flask app are Lightsail (less demanding/smaller requirements), ECS with Fargate or EC2 Instances. You can host your static files on S3, but depending on the amount it might not be worth the effort.