# Find the source code for NGINX installed on Amazon Linux 2

Tags: amazon-web-services, nginx, amazon-linux-2

I was just trying to edit the source code from NGINX installed via amazon-linux-extras as nginx1 to edit the server response header.

I have read that the best and most simple way is to edit the file
`ngx_http_header_filter_module.c` and change the string to whatever server response.

I am using nginx 1.20 and I can't seem to find the source code.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Changing the source code won't help. You would need to recompile nginx and modules and install them. It should be possible to edit the server response header by editing the nginx.conf file. See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/246227/how-do-you-change-the-server-header-returned-by-nginx) for example.